# how to use CCSpriteBatchNode and still use local coordinate?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, textures

Let me give the brief summary of our setup.

There's a world.
Inside the world, there are lots of places.
Inside the places, there are lots of characters.
Now many of the characters share the same texture.

We currently have
world(layer)-batchNode-character sprite.
world(layer)-batchNode-place sprite

Hence character's position is relative to world, not the place it's in(conceptually).

How could we set up class hierarchies so that
we still utilize the power of batchNode
and be able to use the local coordinate for character(relative to place it is in)

Simple structure such as
world(layer)-place(layer)-batchNode-character(sprite) won't work because there will be many common characters in a world but not sharing the batchNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need (multiple) layers. You can have your batch nodes take the place of layers. You may want to have one main layer for user input, or manage user input yourself by registering a touch delegate class with touch dispatcher.

Conceptually what I would recommend the node hierarchy to be:

```
scene (touch delegate)
  batchNode (places)
  batchNode (characters)
```

or

```
scene
  layer (input)
    batchNode (places)
    batchNode (characters)
```

Now assuming that your places (tiled images?) are somehow spread across the world, they each have a position. To have the characters in each place have coordinates relative to the place they're in, you can do one of two things:

1. Set the position of the character batchnode to be the position of the corresponding place. This works if you only batch the characters in that place.
2. If you want to batch all identical characters regardless of place, you can add "dummy" CCSprites (uses a tiny, fully transparent image) to the batch node and position each to be at the position of a specific place. Then add the characters for this place as children of this sprite. If characters move from place to place, remove them from one dummy sprite and add them to the corresponding other dummy sprite.

Finally, you can always create helper methods that transform the position of a sprite to local coordinates based on the place they're in. That way you don't need any specially setup node hierarchy and you can still work with local coordinates where necessary. If you do that, you may find that whether you use local or world coordinates doesn't really make much of a difference. World coordinates are simply character position plus place position, a simple addition/subtraction gets you from world to local coordinates and vice versa.